# Error using sed in shell script trying to replace text containing forward slashes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi3

I ran my shell script on rpi 3. But I got the following error.

> script.sh: 51: script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

my script lines is following.

```
51: lines_to_be_removed=("allow-hotplug wlan0" "iface wlan0 inet manual" "wpa-conf \/etc\/wpa_supplicant\/wpa_supplicant.conf")

52: remove_lines(){
53:    for i in "${lines_to_be_removed[@]}"
54:    do
55:        sudo sed -i "/$i/,1 d" /etc/network/interfaces
56:    done
57: }
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Check lines before 51.

Comment: what do you mean?
do you need to see lines before 51?

Comment: Another possibility is that the shell is not bash.  Show how you're invoking the script and what the shebang line is.  Also, @Cyrus' advice is excellent: copy and paste your complete code (but not the line numbers) into [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: @Pavlov: yes, add some lines before number 51.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
clear
sleep 5s
# Change value for Hotspot name
NETWORK="RPI3-HOTsPOT"
# Change value for Hotspot password
PASSWORD="rpi3hotspot"

sleep 10s
echo 
echo "Running HotSpot Setup ..."
echo 
echo "Checking for network connection ..."
echo
#Check for internet connection
ping -c 1 www.google.com > /dev/null 2>&1
sleep 10s
is_connected=$?
if [ "$is_connected" = "0" ]; then
    echo "Checking for Updates ..."
    sudo apt-get update > /dev/null
 if ! { sudo apt-get update 2>&1 || echo E: update failed; } | grep -q '^[WE]:'; then

Comment: sudo pkill apt-get
        sudo apt-get update
        echo "Installing updates ..."
        echo
            if ! { sudo apt-get update 2>&1 || echo E: update failed; } | grep -q '^[WE]:'; then
                sudo apt-get upgrade -y
            else
                echo "Failed to update. Please restart and check connection"
                exit 1
            fi
        
    else
        echo "Failed to get updates. Please restart and check connection"
        exit 1
    fi

Comment: else
    echo "Please check network connection..."
    echo "Exiting ......"
    echo
    echo "Please Restart to run this Setup Again ..."
    echo
    exit 1
fi

Comment: Hello John,
I added my script in shellcheck.net

Comment: Putting the code here in comments is obviously not very useful. If you don't want to add the code to the actual question (please don't include line numbers!) maybe put it somewhere like https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @Pavlov After you paste your code in shellcheck.net, wait a moment and then shellcheck will display a variety of errors (red) and warnings about your code.  Follow shellcheck's suggestions and your code will be much improved.

Comment: I don't understand the address range `/$i/,1`. The line that matches /$i/ to line 1? But I'm sure it's unrelated to the Unexpected '(' error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this'll solve the problem, but it may help simplify and streamline the solution. Try calling sed once:

```
remove_lines() {
    sed -i '
        /allow-hotplug wlan0/d
        /iface wlan0 inet manual/d
        /wpa-conf \/etc\/wpa_supplicant\/wpa_supplicant.conf/d
    ' /etc/network/interfaces
}
```